# Tablesorter - One column table, remove sorting but keep search for that column

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

[So here is a link to the table](http://sellingtweets.com/5/). I can't disable the sorting feature without also disabling the search for that column as well. Im using the [filter widget external search](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html) incase that helps.

Here is the JS coding

```
$(function() {

var $table = $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
        // filter_anyMatch replaced! Instead use the filter_external option
        // Set to use a jQuery selector (or jQuery object) pointing to the
        // external filter (column specific or any match)
        filter_external : '.search',
        // add a default type search to the first name column
        filter_defaultFilter: { 1 : '~{query}' },
        // include column filters
        filter_columnFilters: false,
        filter_placeholder: { search : 'Search...' },
        filter_saveFilters : true,
        filter_reset: '.reset'

    }
});
// make demo search buttons work
$('button[data-column]').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        totalColumns = $table[0].config.columns,
        col = $this.data('column'), // zero-based index or "all"
        filter = [];

    // text to add to filter
    filter[ col === 'all' ? totalColumns : col ] = $this.text();
    $table.trigger('search', [ filter ]);
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `"sorter-false"` class name to the header:

```
<th class="column-1 sorter-false"></th>
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/661/)

Comment: Thanks. I did try this earlier which works but the up and down arrows don't go away.

Comment: If you are using a custom theme, make sure to include this css definition `.tablesorter thead .sorter-false { background-image: none; }` ([ref in blue theme](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/css/theme.blue.css#L73-L77))